# Load template directory dynamic in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I use Twig in my project, I don't use Symfony as PHP framework.

Here is my constructor :

```
    $this->_template_dir []= '/views/';
    $this->_template_dir []= 'modules/comments/views/';

    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->_template_dir);

    $this->_twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
            'cache' => $this->_cache_dir,
            'debug' => TRUE,
            'auto_escape' => FALSE,
            'autoescape' => FALSE,
            'auto_reload' => ! (ENVIRONMENT == 'production')
    ));
```

Is there a way to set template dir after the constructor ? Like a method :

```
$this->_twig->addTemplateDir('new_folder');
```

I didn't find anything in documentation.

Comment: Seems the `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` has a method [addPath()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_Loader_Filesystem.html#method_addPath)

Comment: Ok addPath does the trick. Thanks ! You can write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use

`$this->_twig->setLoader($this->_template_dir[0])`

after you have initiated twig

Answer (score 0):

The `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` has a method [addPath()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#built-in-loaders)